# Is there a convenient way to construct larger type level Peano numbers using mono-traversable?

Tags: haskell, classy-prelude, peano-numbers

The mono-traversable package uses type level Peano numbers for `MinLen`. I can construct them using chained `Succ`s:

```
toMinLen [1,2,3] :: Maybe (MinLen (Succ (Succ Zero)) [Int])
```

but this quickly gets out of hand:

```
toMinLen [1,2,3] :: Maybe (MinLen (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))))) [Int])
```

Is there a convenient way to construct larger Peano numbers? I see GHC has a TypeLiterals extension but I'm not sure if I can use it here. Alternatively, I can make synonyms like:

```
type One = Succ Zero
type Two = Succ One
```

and so on; does something like that already exist somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TypeLits` is perfectly good for type-level numerals. Also, it's easy to use  it only for syntactic sugar and leave the underlying library-specific implementation unchanged.

```
{-# LANGUAGE
  UndecidableInstances, TypeFamilies,
  DataKinds, TypeOperators #-}

import qualified GHC.TypeLits as TL

data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat

newtype MinLen (n :: Nat) a = MinLen a
```

We have to define a type family that converts a literal to the number type:

```
type family Lit (n :: TL.Nat) :: Nat where
  Lit 0 = Zero
  Lit n = Succ (Lit (n TL.- 1))
```

Now you can use `Lit n` whenever you need a `Nat` literal. In GHCi:

```
>:kind! MinLen (Lit 3)
MinLen (Lit 3) :: * -> *
= MinLen ('Succ ('Succ ('Succ 'Zero)))
```

Comment: Am I  understanding correctly that if we added some code like that to mono-traversable then users would be able to use type level literals more easily?

Comment: I think yes. But note that this is available only from GHC 7.8.

Answer (score 2):

There is a package for this sort of thing: [type-level](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-level). It's a bit intimidating, and I haven't really explored it yet. But you shouldn't need that much power, so you can roll your own simple bits.

If you're willing to use `UndecidableInstances`, things are pretty easy. Something approximately like this (I don't know exactly how the naturals are defined in that library; if it doesn't use `DataKinds`, you may have to use the `*` kind instead of the `Nat` kind, and you may have to write `'Succ` and `'Zero` instead of `Succ` and `Zero`--I'm not too clear on that aspect):

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances, TypeFamilies, DataKinds, TypeOperators #-}

module TAR where

-- You wouldn't actually use this line, because the library
-- provides the naturals
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat

-- Digits and Ten to get things started
type One = Succ Zero
type Two = Succ One
type Three = Succ Two
type Four = Succ Three
type Five = Succ Four
type Six = Succ Five
type Seven = Succ Six
type Eight = Succ Seven
type Nine = Succ Eight
type Ten = Succ Nine

type family Plus (a::Nat) (b::Nat) where
  Plus Zero n = n
  Plus (Succ m) n = Plus m (Succ n)

type family Times (a::Nat) (b::Nat) where
  Times Zero n = Zero
  Times (Succ m) n = Plus n (Times m n)

type Decimal (a::[Nat]) = Decimal' a Zero

type family Decimal' (a::[Nat]) (n::Nat) where
  Decimal' '[] n = n
  Decimal' (a ': bs) n = Decimal' bs (Plus a (Times Ten n))
```

Then you can write something like

```
Decimal '[One, Two, Five]
```

to mean 125.

Answer (score 1):

You could port [`type-natural`'s `QuasiQuoter`s](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-natural-0.2.3.2/docs/Data-Type-Natural.html#g:7).